# Flutter PageView turn and flip animation for book app UI using After Effects

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to perform animation in my flutter app specifically in Pageview widget to swipe pages such as a real book as in the image
[image]

Comment: Please where u able to implement it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, [flip_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flip_widget):

```
FlipWidget(
    key: _flipKey,
    child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
            child: Text("hello"),
        ),
    ),
)
```